# If $x \in c_0 $ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_n|< \infty $ $ \implies x \in l^p$ for $p \in (1,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi I was trying to solve my problem sheet in functional analysis. In order to prove something I need to show that If $x \in c_0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_n|< \infty $$ \implies x \in l^p$ for $p \in (1,\infty)$
My reasoning is that since $x \in c_0$(space of sequences converging to zero), then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N$ we have that

$|x_n|<1$ and therefore $\forall p \in (1,\infty) $ we have that

$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p \leq \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|x_n|$ and hence $x \in l^p$ This is correct right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Adayah Thanks for the help

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| <\infty$ implies $x\in c_0$.

Comment: @Jochen yeah the statement had redundant elements . Sorry